# Finding duplicates from 2 excel spreadsheets on the basis of certain fields

Tags: excel

I have two excel spreadsheets. Both are having same fields/columns e.g Name, Flat No, City, Pin Code etc. I want to compare these 2 sheets and find out duplicates on the basis of some specific fields say Flat No, Building, Location, City. So how can I achieve this?

Will be really grateful if I get assistance for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Take a look at the `VLOOKUP` function. This will give you a field from a matching dataset - or produce an error if nothing can be found...

Comment: Perhaps `concatenate` the identifying fields first into a new column, then use `vlookup` on that field

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement seems quite vague I’d suggest adding a column to indicate which are the source sheets for your data and then appending one sheet to the other. For compariosns, filter one or more columns of the combination.